# Scrolling with input number but stopping the scroll on the main container

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to scroll select my input numbers. But it is also scrolling my container as well. Is there a way to disable scroll while focused in the input number.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FztYT.png

I am using React Typescript with material ui. If you need to see any code let me know.

Comment: Does tabIndex work. Giving a negative value disables focus on that element. Works with keyboards. Try if it works with mouse scrolls.

Comment: @VisakhVijayan Yeah dosen't seem to work.